# How to check if waze can be opened on android device with expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to check if waze can be opened on android device. I'm using react native with expo with managed workflow.I found that i can use expo-linking so i looked for documentation and did it like this

```
Linking.canOpenURL("waze://")
```

This should return true or false. It returns false. But i have waze installed and when i use expo-linking like this:

```
Linking.openURL("waze://")
```

It actually works. But I don't need to open app. I just want to check if it's installed.
So i continued to search for solution. And it seems I need to edit AndroidManifest. Which is kinda problem with managed workflow. But I find a way with using plugins.
So I tried to create plugin like this:

```
const { withAndroidManifest } = require("@expo/config-plugins");

const supportedApps = ["geo", "waze"];
const mapAppIntents = supportedApps.map((app) => {
    return {
        action: {
            $: { "android:name": "android.intent.action.VIEW" },
        },
        data: {
            $: { "android:scheme": app },
        },
    };
});

module.exports = function androidManifestPlugin(config) {
    return withAndroidManifest(config, async (config) => {
        const androidManifest = config.modResults.manifest;
        const existingIntent = androidManifest.queries[0].intent;

        androidManifest.queries[0].intent = existingIntent.concat(mapAppIntents);

        return config;
    });
};
```

and then in app.config.js I set it like this

```
   const withCustomIntentFilter = require("./plugins/withCustomIntentFilter");

module.exports = withCustomIntentFilter({
   expo: {
//rest of params
   }
});
```

But when i build apk for android with expo it still returns false.

Any ideas?